# One latex source producing several pdf files with continuing counters

Tags: counters

I am looking for a way of splitting a textbook into lecturenotes for individual lectures. That is, I have a latex file textbook.tex and I would like to produce pdfs lecture1.pdf, lecture2.pdf.

The crucial feature is that I would like to have consistent numbering of theorems across the files, e.g., Lecture 2 starting with Theorem 5 after Lecture 1 ended with Theorem 4.

Is there any way to do it without creating special tex file for each lecture with counter manually set to the correct number?

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463699/proper-reference-numbers-with-subfiles

Comment: A simpler solution is to use `\include` and `\includeonly`.